# Under which conditions can we have space of functions $\mathbf{S} \rightarrow \mathbf{F}$ spanned by partial maps $h_t$ finite dimensional.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, modules, representation-theory, tensor-products

Comments in the parenthesis () are not part of the text.
From Hochschid's book [Introduction to Affine Algebraic Groups, Chapter 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hwwhk.jpg)

Let $F$ be a field, and let $S$ and $T$ be non-empty sets. Denote by $\mathscr{M}_{F}(S)$ the $F$-algebra of all $F$-valued functions on $S$. There is a canonical map $\pi: \mathscr{M}_{F}(S) \bigotimes \mathscr{M}_{F}(T) \rightarrow \mathscr{M}_{F}(S \times T)$, where $$\pi(f \bigotimes g)(s,t) = f(s)g(t).$$
Evidently, $\pi$ is an F-algebra homomorphism, and it is an elementary exercise in linear algebra to show that $\pi$ is injective(Question 1). Moreover, it is readily seen that the image of $\pi$ consists precisely of those elements $h$ of $\mathscr{M}_{F}(S \times T)$ for which the space of functions $S \rightarrow F$ that is spanned by the partial maps $h_t$, where $h_t(s) = h(s,t)$, is finite-dimensional $(\mathbf{Why?})$. An equivalent condition is obtained, of course, by switching the roles of $S$ and $T$.

$\mathbf{Question}$: Why is the image of $\pi$ finite-dimensional? What I can see is the space of functions $S \rightarrow F$ is finitely generated(i.e. any element of space of functions $S \rightarrow F$ can be written as a finite linear combination of $h_t$) but not finite dimensional(since we do not have finiteness condition on sets $S$ and $T$, their $F$-valued functions or field).

Edit: Question 1: I thought I had checked injectivity of $\pi$ but it turns out checking injectivity of tensor product is highly non-trivial. Injectivity holds if $\mathscr{M}_{F}(S)$ and $\mathscr{M}_{F}(T)$ is finite dimensional, but for infinite dimensional, I do not have proof.

Comment: The claim is not that the image of $\pi$ is finite-dimensional. In general it is not. Let $h = \pi(\sum_{i=1}^\ell f_i \otimes g_i)$. For each $t \in T$, the function $s \mapsto \sum_i f_i(s)g_i(t)$ lies in the vector space span $\langle f_1, \ldots, f_\ell \rangle$. (Think of the $g_i(t)$ as scalars, and the sum as a linear combination of the $f_i$.) So varying $t$, the span of all the $h_t$ is at most $\ell$-dimensional, and contained in $\langle f_1, \ldots, f_\ell \rangle$. This, I'm fairly sure, is what Hochschild is claiming.

Comment: @MarkWildon This works, so far I have read we don't need to know the dimension of ${\pi}$. Injectivity also follows from here since we can write $\sum_{i=1}^{l} f_{i} \otimes g_{i}$ can be written in terms of basis of $\mathscr{M}_{F}(S)$ and $\mathscr{M}_{F}(S)$(not necessarily finite). Thank you.